# Without a calculator, prove: $7^{1/2} + 7^{1/3} + 7^{1/4} < 7$ [solved]

Tags: inequality, exponentiation, square-numbers

I need to prove
$$7^{1/2} + 7^{1/3} + 7^{1/4} < 7$$

I have reached the stage $$1 + 7^{-2/12} + 7^{-3/12} < 7^{1/2}$$, but don’t know if I’m on the right track or what to do next. Thanks

Thanks for the help everyone, much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

We have $\sqrt{7}<3$, $\sqrt[3]{7}<2$ and $\sqrt[4]{7}<2$. Summing up

$$\sqrt{7}+\sqrt[3]{7}+\sqrt[4]{7}<3+2+2=7$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Consider the numbers $9,8,16$. Think of how you can use them to construct an inequality on the LHS. (If you don't get the solution in one-two lines, you're doing something wrong/long-winded)

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt[3]7<2,$$
$$\sqrt7<2.65$$ because $$26\cdot27=676+26=702$$ and from here $$2.65^2=7.0225$$ and 
$$\sqrt[4]7<\sqrt{2.65}<\sqrt{2.89}=1.7.$$
Id est, $$\sqrt7+\sqrt[3]7+\sqrt[4]7<2+2.65+1.7<7.$$

Answer (score 0):

One way (if you have learned calculus) is to consider the function $$f(x) = x-x^{1/2}-x^{1/3}-x^{1/4}$$
We can numerically find zeroes close to $0$ and $6$. Then we can take a look at the derivative:

$$f'(x) = 1-\frac{1}{2}x^{-1/2}-\frac{1}{3}x^{-2/3}-\frac{1}{4}x^{-3/4}$$

The $1$ is constant term and everything else is strictly moving towards $0$ with increasing $x$. So whenever $x$ becomes large enough the $1$ is sure to "win" over the variable terms.

Should be easily finishable from here.

This can be used to prove the inequality for all large enough $x$, so it also works for 8,9,10 et.c.

Comment: I suggest comparing $1+x+x^3$ to $x^9$ this is more natural than rational exponents.

Comment: But is it related to the problem?

Comment: set $x=7^{1/12}$  then $x^6+x^4+x^3<x^{12}\iff x^3+x+1<x^9$...

Comment: zwim: Aha I see. But I don't think it makes this approach any easier. $g_\alpha(x) = x^{-\alpha}$ are very easy elementary functions to show that they are monotonically decreasing for all positive $\alpha$ and also easy to show that this property stacks with addition.